# WP E-commerce: show all products in category

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, e-commerce

How can I show category page that contains all products in this category? I have a menu with categories in the header. Those links are linked to the categories. I need customize the WP E-Commerce category template. Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "wpsc-products_page.php" template? If your theme doesn't have the file already, you can generate it via the WPEC settings page.